# Material Design Setup

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, material-design

I'm trying to set up Material Design so that I can use it for Android 5.0 and fall back to v7-appcompat themes for older devices. Everything that I've read says that when I create the project, there should be two folders, "res/values" and "res/values-v21" or at least in the android view there should be two syles.xml files. However, all I can ever get is just "res/values" and one styles.xml file. What am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't android studio create the folders and .xml files? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can create the values-v21 folder. Where is the problem?

Comment: "I'm trying to set up Material Design so that I can use it for Android 5.0 and fall back to v7-appcompat themes for older devices" -- the idea is that you use `appcompat-v7` for all devices, not just older ones. Due to the requirement to inherit from `ActionBarActivity` to use `appcompat-v7`, it will take a fair bit of code duplication to avoid using it on API Level 21+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create this directory manually. In Android Studio right-click res directory of your project, choose New -> Directory from menu. Enter the name of directory 'values-v21'. Add style.xml file to newly created directory in similar way (New -> File from menu). That's all :)

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the answer. I will do this. However, I still do not understand why these folders and xml files are not generated by default. I have seen a couple tutorials where they are generated by default.

Comment: Well, it's up to Android Studio what project template includes.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can create new directory manually as stated by michal.z . But if you are tiered by making directory every time while creating new project. You can define your own custom template.

Android Studio's templates are based on the **Android ADT Template system**, which is in turn based on FreeMarker.

To create your own custom template just follow this [post](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/215-mobile/6843-custom-projects-in-android-studio.html)

You need to edit template.xml file.